# How i can limit period of post publication?

Tags: posts, query, date-time

I need to limit period od post publication - admin type date, for example, 30.05.2016 in custom fields and then i need to hide custom posts with this date less, then today date

How i can do this?

Comment: You just need to show us what you did so far. But here's a little process. Create a custom cron that runs daily or with custom interval using [`wp_schedule_event()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_schedule_event) and while hooking into this event, verify each post's submission date and get the time difference. If the difference is greater than your length e.g 1month, then use [`wp_update_post()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post) to set the status to pending or something else..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you looked into expire plugins ?
https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=expire

finally wordpress.org/plugins/post-expiring seems to have done the job.

Comment: Oh, thanks! Plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-expiring/ help me!
I exchange post_type in plugin's code and show expire date in additional post column with post meta of this plugin. Work great!

Comment: Don't understood that Gabrial said

Comment: He said that what I came up with was not a proper answer as such.  I should have put that information into a comment, but I didn't have the 50 required points to have rights to comment... so he was just reminding me the rules.

Comment: What I love in this network is how fast people who are not concerned by the question can vote down on an answer...  I admit my answer is of a poor quality, all I was saying is that the keyword for what was looked for was probably "expire"

Comment: Exactly, Antony. I can't formulated my problem and i realy needed keyword "expire")) Thanks again)